# MongoDB is summing numbers incorrectly

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB to sum a number of transactions, however it is returning the wrong values.

All numbers are stored as a long - In mongo shell they appear as NumberLong("5")

I have spent some time looking at my data thinking I had collected it incorrectly, however I now realise MongoDB is not summing the values correctly.

My test data is here: http://pastebin.com/3LNQLFtR

The actual value I am looking for is `165516011841`, however when I do a $sum aggregate in MongoDB it incorrectly reports `1641757914055`.

Here is my aggregate:

```
{$project: {"value": '$o.v'}}
{$group: {"_id":1, "total":{$sum: "$value"}}}
```

Excel has the same issue by the way. The only way to sum it correctly is as they are intended, Int64.

As requested here is a example document:
http://pastebin.com/BD4RuPyg

Edit, it appears that my data (and MongoDB) is correct. I was attempting to reach the Total Received value here: https://blockchain.info/address/1PEDJAibfNetJzM289oXsW1qLAgjYDjLgN

However it appears my number is more accurately a turnover of that particular value, and so better reflects what I am trying to present.

Comment: Can you give the structure of documents (or example of document) in the collection on which the aggregation is performed?

Comment: My first instinct, without testing this, would be that you are aggregating on a subdocument field without unwinding it first, in which case it could actually be picking out incomplete values in your $project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided answer by MongoDB is correct, issue was with proof being incorrect:

https://blockchain.info/address/1PEDJAibfNetJzM289oXsW1qLAgjYDjLgN

Total Received on that page should be 1641757914055 not 165516011841.

Answer (score 1):

Found your issue really interesting and decided to run some tests against the data you provided here http://pastebin.com/3LNQLFtR. There are two text areas on the page I used the data from the first one with 26926 records in it.

- First I inserted the data into excel. Just copied and pasted the data column.
  Then selected all the values to look at the sum result.
- Secondly I inserted it into a mongo collection. Using a simple
  document with one filed.
  `db.testLong1.insert({v:NumberLong(499689200) })` Then run a group
  query, pretty much the same as you did.

  `db.testLong1.aggregate({$project: {"value": "$v"}}, {$group:{"_id":1, "total":{$sum:"$value"}}})`
- Finally I inserted the data into a SQL Server db. Again a simple one
  field table.

  `create table t1(v bigint not null)`

  Inserted all the records with a number of insert statments, like this
  one

  `insert t1 values('241025537')`

  Then just ran this query to get the sum of the values

  `select sum(v) from t1`

All the tools gave me the same result, that is `1641757914055`
How do you know this is wrong?
I've been working with the tools for quite long and never heard about or experienced such an issue. So I tend to believe that it's not mongo that returns an incorrect result but a bug in your system which makes you believe this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The one thing I have noticed, which your answer leaves out, is that he is infact using a subdocument field

Comment: @Sammaye Yeah, I thought about it as well but in this case I would have gotten different result in mongo from those in sql server and excel

Comment: My document layout uses a sub document array, but this was omitted from the question as it is not relevant to the issue at hand. Good question but my aggregate has the required $unwind commands.